# search for a property in objects of array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have a JS array with more objects inside it.
For example my array has the following in it :

```
1 {key:1;value:1}
2 {key:2;value:2}
3 {key:3;value:3}
4 {key:4;value:4}
```

Now i want to insert another element in this array and how can i check if any object already existing does not have the same value . key may or may not differ but i want to have unique values.
NOTE: Original array has objects with multiple properties and not just key or value.
I do not want to use loops.

Comment: **I do not want to use loops** ? Why ?.

Comment: use recursion then and if you use it with loops then your life will be much more easier. Although question still stands why??

Comment: I do not want to use loops beacuse i am already using 5 nested each loops.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly include the jQuery library:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And after that use this script and the function called `check_if_in_array`:

```
_array = [
            {key:1,value:1},
            {key:2,value:2},
            {key:3,value:3},
            {key:4,value:'test'}
        ];

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('Check if in array 5: ' + check_if_in_array(5));
    console.log('Check if in array "test": ' + check_if_in_array('test'));
});

function check_if_in_array(_value){
    var _flag = false;
    _array.forEach(function(el){
        if (el.value == _value) {
            _flag = true;
        };
    });

    return _flag;
};
```